# attaching metatables within tabes

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable, meta-method

I have parser that parses a config file and produces a table.

The resulting table can look something like:

```
root = {
 global = {
 },
 section1 = {
   subsect1 = {
     setting = 1
     subsubsect2 = {
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The goal is to have a table I can read settings from and if the setting doesn't exist, it'll try to grab it from it's parent.  At the top level it will grab from global.  If it's not in global it'll return nil.

I attach metatables to root like this:

```
local function attach_mt(tbl, parent)
    for k,v in pairs(tbl) do
      print(k, v)
      if type(v) == 'table' then
        attach_mt(v, tbl)
        setmetatable(v, {
          __index = function(t,k)
            print("*****parent=", dump(parent))
            if parent then
              return tbl[k]
            else
              if rawget(tbl, k) then
                return rawget(tbl, k)
              end
            end
            print(string.format("DEBUG: Request for key: %s: not found", k))
            return nil
          end
        })
      end
    end
  end

  attach_mt(root)
```

However, when requesting keys it doesn't work.  What appears to be the case is that is always nil. How do I read from the parent table?

Comment: Did you mean `return tbl[k]` or did you mean `return parent[k]`?

Comment: That was it!  thanks I fixed it

Comment: hmm, almost fixed.  doesn't grab from global.

Comment: Yeah, that's not in the normal nesting order so that needs to be explicit (or added to the nesting order). And as was pointed out in a comment on my answer the fix is actually the other way. Fix `if parent then` to `if tbl then` and you don't need the `parent` (which is actually grandparent) argument at all.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I realised what was happening and explicitely add another metatable to root to grab from global.  I'm also skipping the add of metatable on 'global' an don't need that rawget stuff there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
local function attach_mt(tbl, parent)
   setmetatable(tbl, {__index = parent or root.global})
   for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
      if type(v) == 'table' then
         attach_mt(v, tbl)
      end
   end
end
attach_mt(root)
setmetatable(root.global, nil)
```

Comment: Genious, thankyou that's actually a lot simpler and makes sense to me.